# Can't find the marketplace in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-kepler, eclipse-marketplace

I'm working with a fresh copy of Eclipse Kepler but I'm unable to find the marketplace. I know it's normally under 'Help' but it's not there.

Is there an option to make it visible again?

Mayby good to know, I'm working on Ubuntu 12.10

Comment: Some Eclipse downloads don't have the marketplace pre-installed. Does 'About Eclipse / Installation Details / Installed Software' show 'Marketplace Client' in the list?

Comment: No it does not have the Client in the list. Thank you for the explenation!

Comment: For me helped this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21222334/715269

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Some Eclipse downloads don't have the marketplace pre-installed. Does 'About Eclipse / Installation Details / Installed Software' show 'Marketplace Client' in the list?

If not you can install it from Help / Install New Software and select the Kepler site. Marketplace is under General Purpose Tools.

Comment: i'm afraid is not, only for Juno i think

Comment: @d1jhoni1b It is in the Install New Software list for Kepler. Some downloads already have it installed, others do not.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to install the Marketplace itself from the Kepler Update Site.  See http://www.eclipse.org/mpc/ .

Answer (score 1):

For Kepler is on "Help" -> "Eclipse Marketplace..." really easy to find now :)

I've installed

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Download: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz

Version: Kepler Service Release 2
Build id: 20140224-0627

Comment: This depends on which Eclipse client you download, they do not all have this.

Comment: yup sure that's why i'm describing my installed version in this case Kepler Release 2 Build id: 20140224-0627
in case that somehow is having problems well just download Kepler by the way i'm attaching the download link here

http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/SR2/eclipse-java-kepler-SR2-macosx-cocoa-x86_64.tar.gz