# open eclipse Markeplace

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, eclipse-marketplace

I want to use eclipse marketplace for adding svn plugin but when i try to do it i have this exception :

```
Cannot open Eclipse Marketplace
Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Unable to read repository at marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
Unable to read repository at marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Unable to read repository at marketplace.eclipse.org/catalogs/api/p.
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I use eclipse kepler.

have you any suggestions ?

thank you

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server?

Comment: You can change proxy settings under Window >> preferences >> General >> Network Connections

Comment: I don't know if there is a proxy, how can i get this information?

Comment: If you are in a company, most probably you are behind a proxy.

Answer (score 7):

I am afraid, it is not proxy. Nor the antivirus. I had the same problem and neither helped. But your Eclipse simply can't reach a site because java 7 by default makes Eclpse to reach it throught the protocol IP6, that is not really supported by Eclipse, at least in versions till 4.3.

Go to cmd, use

```
setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

restart eclipse and it will work.

Comment: This didn't work for me, I'm behind a proxy and the certificate I see is coming from the proxy. So I need to import this certificate somewhere in eclipse i suppose.

Comment: Surely, you have Eclipse newer than 4.3. I am afraid, now the reason could be different. Find your, recent way and publish it here as another answer.

Comment: BTW, does your jvm has the certificate for the URL you are trying to reach?

Comment: I have `Eclipse Oxygen.1a (4.7.1a)`, I imported the certificate into `cacerts` of my JVM, and I set the `-vm` parameter in the `eclipse.ini` but no luck. Sorry if I commented at the wrong answer!

Comment: The following reference is about different vm key, but the main thought remains the same - to change ini IS NOT ENOUGH!  https://stackoverflow.com/a/10814631/715269